# Is there a way to get JUnit code coverage when running in the browser?

Tags: code-coverage, intern

We are currently working on getting better code coverage for one of our JS libraries. I have the The Intern up and running, and can run tests in the browser. However, our libraries create DOM elements in some of their functions, making it so we can't run JUnit from the terminal because Node.js doesn't allow for DOM construction in tests. Is there a way we can get JUnit code coverage on the html and console output we get when we run The Intern in the browser?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing JSUnit tests not JUnits?

Comment: I'm sure we should, but all of our current reports are JUnit, so we were looking to be able to add our code coverage output to those reports. How would this be done with JSUnit, just curious?

Comment: I'm just totally confused why you'd be using JUnits which are for java to test/cover a JS Library when JSUnit test/cover should be used. Totally confused and this would say to me that if you are completely relying on JUnits to cover the rest of your JS code then your reports are wrong.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. I was curious because my team had asked if it is possible. If the intern can do JSUnits, that is still something. We just need to be able to parse the results we get when we run the browser tests. My question is, what is the best way of going about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. From this link: https://theintern.github.io/intern/#local-selenium

```
Using ChromeDriver (Chrome-only)
If you’re just looking to have a local environment for developing functional tests, a stand-alone ChromeDriver installation works great.

1. Download the latest version of ChromeDriver
2. Set tunnel to 'NullTunnel'
3. Run chromedriver --port=4444 --url-base=wd/hub
4. Set your environments capabilities to [ { browserName: 'chrome' } ]
5. Run the test runner
```

Once you have that setup and running, you can run

```
node_modules/intern/bin/intern-runner.js  config=tests/intern reporters=JUnit filename=junit.xml
```

This will allow the tests to run in a chrome instance, and then output the results to a report that can then be upload somewhere.